# How can I write an Apache rewrite rule to direct non-www requests to the www hosthame, and keep the relative path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that requires non-www to www redirection, but we would like to redirect keeping the relative path of what the user is looking to find.

For example, if the user is looking for `https://example.com/business` we would like it to redirect to `https://www.example.com/business`.

We have tried a great number of different rewrite rules, none of which are working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```